# Change Jquery scroller to move one content at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jquery scroller whichs scrolls vertically up and down.

Scroller contains time from 5:00 am to 10:00pm. I want the scroller to move only one time upward on a single click. The onload scroller function as below:

```
jQuery.noConflict(); 
/* calling thumbnailScroller function with options as parameters */
(function($){ 
window.onload=function(){ 
    $("#tS3").thumbnailScroller({ 
        scrollerType:"clickButtons", 
        scrollerOrientation:"vertical", 
        scrollSpeed:1, 
        scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc", 
        scrollEasingAmount:800, 
        acceleration:1, 
        scrollSpeed:300, 
        noScrollCenterSpace:10, 
        autoScrolling:0, 
        autoScrollingSpeed:2000, 
        autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad", 
        autoScrollingDelay:500 
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

I have created a jsfiddle to show my scroller issue. Now scroller moves up multiple times upwards on a single click. I want to change this scroller functionality to move one time upward at a time.

http://jsfiddle.net/VT4L6/5/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The scroller not working at all in firefox =(

Comment: In jsfiddle its not working.But as html its working.Please help.

Comment: do you have a working page ? now too difficult to debug

Comment: http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/ScrollerBCKUP/index.html see in html its working fine.

Comment: I have added all files into the external resources and all js files in this html into the jsfiddle.But its not working in jsfiddle

Comment: I think this the scroller you are using??
http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_thumbnail_scroller_multiple.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the original plugin demo source, hack the plugin a bit, add a `step` option, see [<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/VT4L6/10/)

```
(function($){
    $("#tS3").thumbnailScroller({ 
        scrollerType:"clickButtons", 
        scrollerOrientation:"vertical", 
        scrollSpeed:2, 
        scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc", 
        scrollEasingAmount:800, 
        acceleration:4, 
        scrollSpeed:800, 
        noScrollCenterSpace:10, 
        autoScrolling:0, 
        autoScrollingSpeed:2000, 
        autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad", 
        autoScrollingDelay:500,
        step:1/6 // You can change this more and less, and see the different
    });
})(jQuery);
```

P.S. your demo so orderless, so I use the plugin demo. and this wasted me hours O.O